# How it is possible to cast parent to child in c#

Tags: c#, oop, stack, heap-memory

A few days ago in an interview, i was asked to explain following cases:

```
public class Parent
{

}
public class Child:Parent
{

}
```

Case1:

```
Parent p = new Child();
    var c = (Child)p;
```

Case2:

```
    Parent p = new Parent();
    var c = (Child)p;
```

I said `case1` is valid and `case2` is invalid , but he asked:

> Why `case2` is invalid while both `p` variable in `case1` and `case2`
> are Type of `Parent` class?

In case2 we get runtime exception by following message:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Parent' to type 'Child

While in `case1` `p` variable was also type of `Parent` class.

He wanted me to explain it from point of `stack` and `heap` memory.

Have you any idea?

**Update:**

The very spot that interviewer misguided me was exactly where he said in both cases `p` is type of 'parent' class, based on the answers, just static types of both variables are 'parent', but in run-time they have different types and it's run-time type that really matters.

Comment: Because in case 2 `p` isn't a `Child` type and therefor cannot be cast into one. In case 1 this isn't a problem because, although stored in a `Parent` variable, `p` actually **IS** a `Child` instance. You can compare this by creating an `new object()` instance. Anything is an object in c# but an object is not everything.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why downcasting is not allowed in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728416/why-downcasting-is-not-allowed-in-c) and [How to create a new object instance of class being the same type of another instance by only knowing it as base class type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65913153/how-to-create-a-new-object-instance-of-class-being-the-same-type-of-another-inst/65913434#65913434)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Upcasting and its effect on the heap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390220/upcasting-and-its-effect-on-the-heap)

Comment: OK, then will it be correct to say 'p' in case1 is type of Child but it's type is defined on runtime not compile time? @Jack T. Spades

Comment: @Abolfazl No, that's not correct. it is "defined" at compile-time, and the object instance being of the expected type is created at runtime. It is what we call *strong typing*: [Why is C# statically typed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/859186/why-is-c-sharp-statically-typed)

Comment: but in case1 after it gets 'p' type by 'p.GetType()' it says  'p' is type of 'Child', but before running program it is known as 'Parent' type.

Comment: @Abolfazl It's [polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/#58197730): you have a Child known as Parent, but it's a Child. Legal in [OOP](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mkagrahari/introduction-to-object-oriented-programming-concepts-in-C-Sharp) | [Classes](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/84c85b/object-oriented-programming-using-C-Sharp-net) | [Abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58765776/#58766026) | [Encapsulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257849/#58258056) | [Interface & Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914802/#58174007)

Comment: I wonder what the interviewer was getting at by asking about stack and heap storage; the question as you've described it has very little to do with either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must make a distinction between the static type of a variable (the type known at compile time) and the run time type of an object reference assigned to a variable.

The static type of `p` is `Parent` in both cases because it is declared as `Parent p`. No matter what you assign it. You may even assign it `null`.

The run time type of the value of `p` after the assignment is `Child` in the first case and `Parent` in the second case. It would be undetermined if `p` was `null`.

It is okay to assign a `Child` to a `Parent`, because the `Child` class derives from `Parent`. A `Child` is therefore a `Parent` (in OO terms).

However, a `Parent` is not a `Child`, because it does not derive from it. Therefore, in the second case, you cannot cast `p` to `Child`. In the first case the cast is valid, because you cast the object to its actual run time type. It tells the compiler, I know that this object assigned to a `Parent` variable is a `Child`, so, please, treat it as a `Child`. This does not involve any conversion; however, a runtime check will be performed, possibly throwing an exception, if the cast was not allowed.

You were asked to explain it from point of view of stack and heap memory. I'm sorry to say, but this has absolutely nothing to do with stack or heap memory. It has to do with inheritance rules and assignment compatibility.

Of course, here we are dealing with reference types (classes). This allows us to derive `Child` from `Parent`. This would not be possible with value types (structs). The point is reference type versus value type, not heap versus stack, which is an implementation detail. And btw., a value type (struct) field in a class will also be stored on the heap.

See also: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail, Part One](https://ericlippert.com/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/) and [Two](https://ericlippert.com/2009/05/04/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-two/) (Eric Lippert's blog)

---

You did not ask for it but casting to a derived type is mostly preceded by a type test, because you usually do not know the run time type in advance. Let us say that the `Child` class adds a new method `DriveParentsToDespair()` (only children can do this). Then you could use [Type testing with pattern matching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-cast#type-testing-with-pattern-matching) to test the type and assign it to a new variable at the same time:

```cs
if (p is Child child) {
    child.DriveParentsToDespair();
}
```

This avoids an exception in case `p` has a run time type of `Parent`.

Comment: is it kind of  'dynamic polymorphism'?

Comment: @Abolfazl It ***IS*** polymorphism (dynamic) as indicated by my comments: *manipulating a child only knowing an ancestor* (using upcast).

Comment: Static and compile-time type was a good point.

Comment: Polymorphism is dynamic and comes into play when you are calling a virtual method. E.g. If `Parent` had a virtual Print method printing "I am a parent" to the console and the `Child`  class did override this method to have it print "I am a child", then the outcome of calling `p.Print();` depends on the run time type of `p`.

Comment: Yeah you are right, polymorphism is a vast concept in 'oop'.

Comment: the exact point as you mentioned in your answer was the we need to differentiate between static type and runtime type.

Comment: Your answer was a great help.@OlivierJacot-Descombes